Compare effect of two coefficients in logit model
I have a logit model with multiple independents qualitatives variables (A, B, C), and I would like to compare the probability of success between individuals who have a certain profile.
For instance, individuals that have this profile :

A = 1 ; B = 2 and C = 3

are more or less likely to succeed than individuals who have, for instance, this profile :

A = 3 ; B = 1 and C = 2

What statistics can I use ? I've tried to compute the predicted probabilities for selected individuals, but I was wondering if a more statistically correct tool exists.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Search here for logit marginal effects.

thank you, when what I'm searching is in fact of to estimate a combined marginal effect. For instance, do woman (A) that have a degree (B) have more chance to get a job that men (A) whithout the same degree (B) ?
